# Checking values in this array, JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this array (JQuery) where I add all my form's controls, it looks like:

```
var     name       = $("#name"),
        surname    = $("#surname"),
        address    = $("#address"),
        phone      = $("#phone"),
        photo      = $("#photo"),
        grade      = $("#grade"),
        profession = $("#profession"),
        email      = $('#email'),
        title      = $('#title'),

                    allFields =    $([]).add(name)
                                        .add(surname)
                                        .add(address)
                                        .add(phone)
                                        .add(photo)
                                        .add(grade)
                                        .add(profession)
                                        .add(email)
                                        .add(title)
                                        .add(grade);
```

I want to check the values of each element into the 'allFields' array with

```
function checkingFieldsArentEmpty(){

              for (var f in allFields){
                    if(f.val() === null)
                        //if any val is null just return false
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

I need ideas in order to improve the last function. Thanks.

Comment: What aspect do you want to improve? Your valid var is unnecessary, just return true at the end.

Comment: Isn't `f` already an jQuery object? `allFields[f].val()` seems wrong, shouldn't it just be `f.val()` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace that function with:

```
function checkingFieldsArentEmpty(){
    return !(allFields.filter(":input[value]").length != allFields.filter(":input").length);
}
```

Comment: @Felix Guerrero: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/): *Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.*

Comment: @Felix Guerrero - I don't understand, the function in your post applies to all the elements contained within `allFields`.

Comment: **I** *think* that the **other** Felix thinks that `:input` only applies to `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var names = ["name", "surname", "address", "phone", "photo",
  "grade", "profession", "title"];
var allFields = {}
$.each(names, function(i, name) {
  allFields[name] = $("#" + name).val();
});
```

and then you can do:

```
if (allFields.name) { // true if it has a value, false for ""
  ...
}
```

The way you're doing it is a little convoluted. Do you want an array or a jQuery object?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/core_javascript_1.5_reference/objects/array/reduce):

```
function checkingFieldsArentEmpty(){
    return allFields.reduce(function(prev, curr, index, array) {
        // for checking for emptiness just add  && cur.val() !== "" 
        return prev && curr.val() !== null; 

    }, true);
}
```

Btw. using jQuery to create and populate the array seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 1):

`hasEmptyFields = !!$.grep(allFields, function(a) { return a.val() === null; }).length`